# how to cast nullable tinyint in linq to sql?

Tags: linq-to-sql, casting

**I want to cast `Nullable Tinyint` column to `int` value in Linq to SQL ?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well By default, it is generated as Byte and not Integer, but you can go to code view and change the type, though that is **not recommended**, as whenever you **drop something again** from your database, the **change you made will go away**.

So I think working with byte is fine. isn't it?